# Can't connect to Oracle Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I have a problem with **Oracle Express Edition**. I can open and run commands in the Data Base by using **sqlplus**, but then I try to connect to Data Base by using **sql developer** it doesn't work. It's strange because I have many other remote Oracle databases and I can connect to them by using **sql developer** or other tools like **IDEA**. May be something wrong with listener?

When I try to connect I get **timed out on connection to port 1521**.

```
Connection to @myhost.company.com failed.
```

**lsnrctl status**

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-╤┼═-2017 12:04:43
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
C:\Users\luchser>lsnrctl status 
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-╤┼═-2017 12:11:20
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                21-╤┼═-2017 14:21:26
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 49 min. 53 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE

Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\localhost\listener\alert\log.xml

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost.company.com)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost.company.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.company.com)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

**tnsping XE 10**

```
C:\Users\luchser>tnsping XE 10

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 26-╤┼═-2017 14:49:12

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.company.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))

OK (0 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
```

**sqlplus user/password@XE**

```
C:\Users\luchser>sqlplus my_user/my_password@XE
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ┬Є ╤хэ 26 14:50:11 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
```

The last just hags and nothing happens.

Comment: you need to post the error.

Comment: It's time out on connection to port 1521 (which is standard port for listener).

Comment: can you post the screenshot of error ?

Comment: I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this configuration, listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.
You can make a connection only on the local database, you can not make a remote connection to the database, because The listener listens only to IP localhost.
You must add an external IP to the listener configuration. listener.ora

```
    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP DB server>)(PORT = 1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))

      )
)
```

Add an exception for port 1521 and port range (32768-65536) for the firewall on the database server, this is necessary for the SQL * NET protocol.
On the client machine, you need to fix tnsnames.ora,
It is necessary to replace localhost with the IP address of the database server.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP DB server>)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. But it wasn't a problem. See updated files.

Comment: Diagnose the network connection to the database.
1) `telnet myhost.company.com 1521`
2) `tnsping XE 10`
3) `sqlplus user/password@XE`

Comment: I don't have telnet. I've run last two commands and added results from them to question.

Comment: Connection to the database successfully. The problem in configuring sql developer.
Give screenshots of the connection settings to the database in sql developer.
Oracle XE database and sql developer are on the same computer?

Comment: It was solved today by restarting listener service and database service. Thank you for care.